# Using aggregates inside of control flow functions

Tags: mysql, aggregate, control-flow

The problem is this: create a query that will Group the IP addresses and display a sum of the number of requests by each IP address that had a return code (`retcode`) of greater than 300 order this query by the `retcode` field in descending order.

What I’ve come up with is this(after many hours of struggling with it)

```
SELECT ipno, retcode, IF(retcode > 300, 1, 0) AS 'return'
FROM WebLog 
GROUP BY ipno
HAVING SUM(retcode) > 300
ORDER BY retcode DESC
```

Of course it doesn't answer the question, I'm just running out of solutions.

Is there any way to use aggregate functions in an IF or CASE statement, such as:

```
IF(retcode > 300, SUM retcode, 0)
```

I think this would work if I knew how to properly write it in a query.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem doesn't make sense.   One can group & count on IP address, as in the following query:

```
SELECT   ipno, COUNT(*)
FROM     Weblog
WHERE    retcode > 300
GROUP BY ipno
```

However, suppose that there are two requests from a particular IP but with different return codes (say 350 and 400); the above query will show a count of two for that address, but what does it mean to sort the results by return code when (now that the results have been grouped) there is now no single such code for that one IP address?

MySQL is exceptional in that it permits you to access "hidden" columns (such as `retcode` in the above query) without encompassing in an aggregate function; other RDBMS would raise an error with the query you gave in your question.  However, for performance reasons MySQL chooses an indeterminate value amongst those in each group for the hidden column so unless they are all the same one should not rely on the results.

Perhaps you want to group on `ipno` *and* `retcode`:

```
SELECT   ipno, retcode, COUNT(*)
FROM     Weblog
WHERE    retcode > 300
GROUP BY ipno, retcode
ORDER BY retcode DESC
```